# How to style the last element of every row or lists using nth child expression

Tags: css, css-selectors

Am having a `ul` lists in which each lists are floated into left side which has `width:24%;` of ul's full width each list has right margin to give some white space.

```
ul.thumbs {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.thumbs li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 1.3%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.no_rmargin {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

here i use a class `.no_rmargin` to every last `li` it's hard to add this to last list of a row every time when its load dynamically is there any child expression to do apply on this case? like `nth-child(4n)` [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/aVe5Z/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `nth-child(4n)` would work perfectly.

You would be using it on `ul.thumbs li`

```
ul.thumbs li:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

I changed the styling for example purposes.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LsXPK/) - I think this is what you want.. unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: ANd one more think in case of IE?? what should we do?

Comment: @VivekVikranth Usage of `nth-child` **[isn't supported by IE 8 <](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)** .. so if you only need to support 9, you're fine. If you do, however, need to support IE8 and lower, you have a few options - both of which involve JavaScript. You could either use a polyfill, or you could use **[jQuery's `nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**